# How to make more than 2 value show in 2 textboxes using the value property

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble displaying the answers in two different disabled input textboxes. I'm not sure if it is my if statement or if it is my calling of the function. I called it in the else statement for it to show in the disabled input.

```html
<head>
    <script>
    "use strict";
    var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };


    //make change
    var makeChange = function(quarters, dimes) {
        var quarter_value = 25;
        var dime_value = 10;

        var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
        if (quarter_value <= cents){
            var quarters = parseInt(cents / quarter_value);
            var changeValue = parseInt(quarters - cents);
            return quarters;
        }
        if (dime_value <= changeValue) {
            var dimes = parseInt(changeValue / dime_value);
            return dimes;
        }
    };

    //validate entry 0-99
    var processEntries = function() {

        var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);

        if ( isNaN(cents) || cents < 0 || cents > 99) {
            alert("Must be a number 0 - 99");
        }
        else {
            $("quarters").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
            $("dimes").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
    };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Change Calculator</h1>

    <label>Enter amount of change due (0-99):</label>
    <input type="text" id="cents" />

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" id="calculate" /><br><br>

    <label for="quarters">Quarters:</label>
    <input type="text" id="quarters" disabled><br>

    <label for="dimes">Dimes:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dimes" disabled><br>

    <label for="nickels">Nickels:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nickels" disabled><br>

    <label for="pennies">Pennies:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pennies" disabled><br>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. Can you include the calling code as well?

Comment: do you mean the HTML

Comment: What exactly is the question?  You say you are having trouble, but you don't say what the trouble is.

Comment: when I run it I am get the right answer for the quarters but it looks like the dimes is just taking on the quarter value.

Comment: Did you try opening the debug window and stepping through the code to see what is happening?

Comment: ya something is going wrong in the second if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.  If you want to use a makeChange() function still then let me know.

```js
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("cents").value);
  if(total !== total) { return;}

  var quarters = Math.floor(total / 25);
  total -= quarters * 25;

  var dimes = Math.floor(total / 10);
  total -= dimes * 10;

  var nickels = Math.floor(total / 5);
  total -= nickels * 5;

  var pennies = total;
  total -= pennies;

  document.getElementById("quarters").value= quarters;
  document.getElementById("dimes").value= dimes;
  document.getElementById("nickels").value= nickels;
  document.getElementById("pennies").value= pennies;
});
```

```html
<h1>Change Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <label>Enter amount of change due (0-99):</label>
  <input type="text" id="cents" />
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" id="calculate" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="quarters">Quarters:</label>
  <input type="text" id="quarters" disabled="disabled" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="dimes">Dimes:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dimes" disabled="disabled" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="nickels">Nickels:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nickels" disabled="disabled" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="pennies">Pennies:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pennies" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome but I'm really trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here I am again and I am learning you see anything that doesn't look right

Comment: what is this doing                                                                                                if (total != total) { return;}

Comment: That is checking to make sure that total is a number.  There is a utility function isNaN() that could also be used here, but I don't recall if that is universally supported so I did it the "old way".  Since NaN == NaN returns false that statement stops us from working with input that is not a number.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
```

"cents" is not a tag name, it is an id:

```
var cents = parseInt($("#cents").value);
```

The same here

```
$("quarters").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
$("dimes").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
```

It should be

```
$("#quarters").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
$("#dimes").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Oddly, when I turned colleen's code into a snippet, `$("cents")` and `parseInt($("cents").value)` both _worked!_ and `var cents` had the correct value that I had entered. `???!`

Comment: OH!  It's because it has its own `$` function!  `var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
      };`

Answer (score 0):

I have annotated your code as best as I could by noting where things might be redefined.  The biggest issue is in makeChange().  If you had a way to update the running total via the input "cents" then much of your code would have worked.  Basically, the variable changeValue could have been used to update the input and then dimes would work like quarters.  I am not keen on that approach and I hope my annotations point you in a better direction

```js
// ---------------------------
// $() shall be sugar for document.getElementById()
// Note: could be a little confusing as some might expect $() to
// be a jQuery result.
// ---------------------------
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
// ---------------------------

// ---------------------------
// Validate entry 0-99
// ---------------------------
var processEntries = function() {
  var cents = parseInt( $("cents").value );
  
  // ---------------------------
  // Let's set some denominations so it is harder to mess things up.
  // You did somehting similar in makeChange()
  // ---------------------------
  var denom = {
    quarter : 25,
    dime: 10,
    nickel : 5,
    penny : 1
  };
  // ---------------------------
  
  
    if ( isNaN(cents) || cents < 0 || cents > 99){
      alert("Must be a number 0 - 99");

      // ---------------------------
      // At this point we can abort.
      // Rather than an "if else" you might just have this "if" ending
      // in a "return"
      // ---------------------------
    }   
    else {
      // ---------------------------
      // Our amount is good, so lets calculate the change.
      // ---------------------------

      // ---------------------------
      // We want to update the input "quarters" with the number of quarters
      // in the change by calling the makeChange() function.
      //
      // Note, the variable quarters and $("quarters") are actually the same
      // thing. This may or may not be what you are expecting.
      //
      // The variable quarters is being created automatically by the browser
      // because there is an element with that id.  You should probably not
      // rely on this fact. If you intended to pass in the element quarters
      // into your makeChange() then you probably want to do so more explicitely
      // as $("quarters") or define a new variable
      //
      // var quarters = $("quarters");
      //
      // At this point it might be valuable to think about what makeChange()
      // is/should be doing.  It looks like you don't want makeChange() to both
      // calculate the change AND update your GUI. I think that is a good
      // separation.  If that is the case, then what makeChange() really needs to
      // know is what the outstanding amount is.
      //
      // The next question might be is makeChange() called once like
      // makeChange(98) and returns an object or array of the number of each coins
      // or is makeChange() called once for each type of coin returning just the
      // number of that coin.  It looks like you are after the latter and that is
      // fine though it also means we need to track the total in the main code.
      //
      // So, if the above is correct, then we probably want makeChange() to have
      // a slightly different signature.  I'll call a new function makeChange2()
      // with this proposal. makeChange2(outstandingBallance, coinDenomination)
      // and we will expect it to return an integer.
      // ---------------------------

      // ---------------------------
      // $("quarters").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
      var quartersReturned = makeChange2(cents, denom.quarter);
      cents = cents - quartersReturned * denom.quarter;
      $("quarters").value = quartersReturned;
      // ---------------------------

      // ---------------------------
      // $("dimes").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
      var dimesReturned = makeChange2(cents, denom.dime);
      cents = cents - dimesReturned * denom.dime;
      $("dimes").value = dimesReturned;
      // ---------------------------

      // ---------------------------
      var nickelsReturned = makeChange2(cents, denom.nickel);
      cents = cents - nickelsReturned * denom.nickel;
      $("nickels").value = nickelsReturned;
      // ---------------------------

      // ---------------------------
      var penniesReturned = makeChange2(cents, denom.penny);
      cents = cents - penniesReturned * denom.penny;
      $("pennies").value = penniesReturned;
      // ---------------------------
      
      // ---------------------------
    }
};
// ---------------------------

// ---------------------------
// makeChange2()
// Given a total and a denomination return the maximum number of coins.
// ---------------------------
function makeChange2(outstandingBallance, coinDenomination) {
  return Math.floor(outstandingBallance / coinDenomination);
}
// ---------------------------

// ---------------------------
// makeChange()
// No longer called, but let's take a look at it.
// We pass in some GUI elements and return something... looks like an integer
// ---------------------------
var makeChange = function(quarters, dimes){
  // ---------------------------
  // Set some standard denominations.  Looks good.  We now do something similar
  // outside this function.
  // ---------------------------
  var quarter_value = 25;
  var dime_value = 10;
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // Get the outstanding amount.  Looks good, again we get this outside this scope now 
  // ---------------------------
  var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // If the outstanding acount is more than a quarter, then return some number of quarters
  // ---------------------------
  if (quarter_value <= cents){
    // ---------------------------
    // Careful here, you just changed what quarters means.
    // You might also want to use Math.floor() to be more explicite.
    // ---------------------------
    var quarters = parseInt(cents / quarter_value);
    // ---------------------------

    // ---------------------------
    // It looks like you want to potentiall calculate the value of the change
    // about to be given, but remember quarters in now the number of quarters
    // to potentially give so (quarters - cents) is probably not what you wanted here.
    // maybe more like:
    //
    // var changeValue = quarters * quarter_value;
    // or
    // var changeValue = cents - quarters * quarter_value;
    //
    // having done that though, you would still likely want to do "something" with changeValue
    // ---------------------------
    var changeValue = parseInt(quarters - cents);
    // ---------------------------

    // ---------------------------
    // return the number of quarters to be given
    // ---------------------------
    return quarters;
    // ---------------------------
  }
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // You might have wanted to do something similar to what you did with quarters here.
  // See notes above.
  //
  // BUT, changeValue likely never gets set correctly.
  // it exists (thanks to hoisting) but is undefined if there are no quarters.
  // If there are quarters then we already exitted above.
  //
  // Assuming you wanted to call this function multiple times, changeValue would have had to
  // update $("cents").value with the running total and that is probably not a great idea.
  // If you did, then the variable cents could have been used here rather than changeValue.
  // ---------------------------
  if (dime_value <= changeValue){
    var dimes = parseInt(changeValue / dime_value);
    return dimes;
  }
  // ---------------------------

};
// ---------------------------

window.onload = function() { $("calculate").onclick = processEntries; };
```

```html
<h1>Change Calculator</h1>

<label>Enter amount of change due (0-99):</label>
<input type="text" id="cents" />

<input type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" id="calculate" /><br><br>

<label for="quarters">Quarters:</label>
<input type="text" id="quarters" disabled><br>

<label for="dimes">Dimes:</label>
<input type="text" id="dimes" disabled><br>

<label for="nickels">Nickels:</label>
<input type="text" id="nickels" disabled><br>

<label for="pennies">Pennies:</label>
<input type="text" id="pennies" disabled><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with the `makeChange` function, so I'm only going to concentrate on that.

```js
//make change
var makeChange = function(quarters, dimes) {
    var quarter_value = 25;
    var dime_value = 10;

    var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
    if (quarter_value <= cents){
        var quarters = parseInt(cents / quarter_value);
        var changeValue = parseInt(quarters - cents);
        return quarters;
    }
    if (dime_value <= changeValue) {
        var dimes = parseInt(changeValue / dime_value);
        return dimes;
    }
};
```

The function is taking parameters `quarters` and `dimes`, but then you declare local variables `var quarters = parseInt(cents / quarter_value);` so the local variable hides the parameter.

Even if you did not re-declare them, assigning values to parameters *does not* change the values that were passed into the function — javascript passes by value, not by reference.

You set `var changeValue = parseInt(quarters - cents);` and then use `changeValue` later in the dime_value comparison. This works because in javascript `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function, so what you effectively have is:

```js
var makeChange = function(quarters, dimes) {
    var quarter_value = 25;
    var dime_value = 10;
    var changeValue;

    var cents = parse.....
```

Beware that in *most* other languages this would not work, because changeValue would exist only within the if-block where it was declared, and would no longer exist in the `if (dime_value < changeValue)` statement.

Using `parseInt(cents / quarter_value)` works, getting only the integer part of the division, e.g. parseInt(71 / 25) produces 2, but it's confusing — `Math.trunc(cents / quarter_value)` shows what you're doing better ... divide then truncate the result.

The function makeChange also knows about the input field `cents`. When you call it twice:

```js
$("quarters").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
$("dimes").value = makeChange(quarters, dimes);
```

...each time it is getting the value entered in the *cents* field, so each time it is doing the *quarters* calculation and returning that, unless cents < 25 then it will do the dimes calculation and return *that*.  In either case, the value of the *quarters* and *dimes* parameters *do not change* as I mentioned before.

Since you can't return values through parameters, you'd be better off passing a single numeric parameter `cents` to `makeChange = function(cents)` and returning an *object* that holds quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.

```js
var makeChange = function(cents) {
    var quarter_val = 25;
    var dime_val    = 10;
    var nickel_val  =  5;

    var coins = {
            'quarters' : 0,
            'dimes'    : 0,
            'nickels'  : 0,
            'pennies'  : 0
        };

    var remaining = cents; // how much of the original cents value remains

    // Figure out how many quarters. Don't have to test if (quarter_val < cents) first
    // because .trunc() of a fraction will produce 0 quarters
    // e.g. 10 / 25 == 0.4 and Math.trunc(0.4) is 0
    coins.quarters = Math.trunc(remaining / quarter_val);
    // Reduce the remaining amount by the value of the quarters.
    remaining = remaining - (coins.quarters * quarter_val);

    // Now do the same for dimes and nickels, and what is left then is pennies
    coins.dimes = Math.trunc(remaining / dime_val);
    remaining = remaining - (coins.dimes * dime_val);

    coins.nickels = Math.trunc(remaining / nickel_val);
    remaining = remaining - (coins.nickels * nickel_val);

    coins.pennies = remaining;

    return coins;
};
```

Calling it now would be like

```
var change = makeChange( parseInt($("cents").value) );
$("quarters").value = change.quarters;
$("dimes").value = change.dimes;
// ...etc...
```